# How to get the sum of the values from a list?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

This is the code I wrote in View and I want to display the total number of calories at the end of each day, depending on the existing aliments. How can I do that?  Here, I've got the calorie values directly from my data base.

```
  @model Database.MealPlanner
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<div>
    <h4>Aliments</h4>
    <hr />
    <ul>

        @foreach (var weekDay in @Model.MealPlannerAliments.GroupBy(q => q.WeekDay).ToList())
        {
            <li class="custom-list-heading list-unstyled"><b>@weekDay.Key</b></li>
            foreach (var item in weekDay)
            {
                <li id="alimentsByDay">

                    <div>
                        <p>@item.Aliment.Name (Calories: @item.Aliment.NutritionalValue.Calories  )</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an ex. I want to display at the end of the day, let's say: **Total Number of Calories/Marti** : 618

[image]

Comment: Linq has a sum() have a look at that and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: You could have different ways to reach this purpose: via client, via server, and it could be implemented in differently for each solution you choose. By the way, I think that it's better to calculate it in server side, modifying the Model of the View adding a "TotalCaloriesAmount" property, calculated in the controller.
The right formula to have this result should be
MealPlannerAliments.GroupBy(q => q.WeekDay).Sum(item=>item.Aliment.NutritionalValue.Calories)

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry! I have edited just now, and I added a picture too. I I have no attempt to solve it with jQuery because I don't know how. I am a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and the [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method. Something like

```
weekDay.Sum(x => x.Aliment.NutritionalValue.Calories)
```

Comment: Great! :) happy to help